# How to download IntelliJ IDEA JavaBeans component of the JAR file

Tags: java, forms, jar, intellij-idea, javabeans

How to insert a palette component of the jar file?

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
* Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
* User: user
* Date: 05.07.13
* Time: 17:51
* To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
*/
public class ImageViewerBean extends JLabel {
private File file=null;
int XPREFSIZE=200;
int YPREFSIZE=200;
public ImageViewerBean(){
setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
}

public void setFileName(String fileName)
{
File file1=new File(fileName);
try {
setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(file)));
} catch (IOException e) {
file=null;
setIcon(null);
}
}

public String getFileName(){
if (file!=null)
return file.getPath();
else
return null;
}

public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
return new Dimension(XPREFSIZE,YPREFSIZE);
}
}
```

Manifest:

Manifest-Version: 1.0

Name: C:\Users\user\IdeaProjects\AWTLearn\src\ImageViewerBean.java
Java-Bean: True

In the manifesto, all strictly no extra spaces at the end of an empty string.

Comment: Can you try to clarify your question a bit? I'm not sure about the others, but as for me, your question is confusing the heck out of me.

Comment: Please supply your source code with proper formatting, tab indents, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [Adding GUI Components and Forms to the Palette](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/adding-gui-components-and-forms-to-the-palette.html) on the IDEA web help page.